# Why this code isnt working?

Tags: jquery

I want jquery to get input data which should be a color name and change the background color of that box. Can't undersrand why val() isnt working here.

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    $("#box").css("background-color", "$("#textValue").val()");
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textValue">
<button id="button1">&nbsp;Change color&nbsp;</button>
<div id="box">This is a test box.</div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have quotes around `$("#textValue").val()`

Comment: Didn't you see the syntax error in the console? Did you even check before posting?

Comment: I'd also expect your IDE to warn you about it.

Comment: Sorry sir, im using NP++. My machine is super slow having a single core cpu. So i cant use better ide's. Running debugger in firefox resulted in a syntex error. Actually im a newbie, couldnt figure out where the mistake was. Thanks for your kind help sir. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#button1").click(function() {
      $("#box").css("background-color", $("#textValue").val());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button1").click(function() {
   $("#box").css("background-color", $("#textValue").val());
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textValue">
<button id="button1">&nbsp;Change color&nbsp;</button>
<div id="box">This is a test box.</div>
```